# save dataframe to mat-File

Tags: matlab, dataframe, scipy, mat

I have a dataframe in Format (300, 2) and I want to save it to a Mat-File with the same attributes (300 rows and 2 columns.

```
sio.savemat(r"C:\Users\Userprio\Desktop\speed.mat", {name: row.values for name, row in Info_speed.items()})
```

but with this method I only get 1 Mat-File with 2 Names (names of the 2 columns) and in the Format (1,300)

How do I do it properly?

Comment: `savemat` saves numpy arrays.  Construct the desired array first.

Comment: @hpaulj I don´t get it. I did allready create the dataframe, why can´t I just save it in this format as a Mat-File?

Comment: Do you understand the difference between `numpy` array and `pandas` dataframe?

Comment: I meant 'first' before saving.  You can't save the dataframe directly.  `savemat` cannot convert a dataframe into a MATLAB compatible dataset (if there is one)

Comment: oooh okay. I didn´t know that I can´t konvert a dataframe directly into a Mat-File :(  Then How can I solve my problem the best way?